# Support for offline storage in Javafx 2.x

Tags: storage, offline, javafx-2

I have an application that shall support offline storage of user data in case the server is unreachable. In Javafx 1.3 that was achieved via the classes javafx.io.Storage and javafx.io.Resource.

When migrating to Javafx 2.0 these classes have been discontinued. I believe that the guys at Oracle have an equivalent functionality for it in Java.

My question is What is the equivalent of the aforementioned classes in Javafx 2.0 What I want is to specify a resource name to which I can store data without worrying where it is exactly stored on the client file system, the same as browsers cookies.

Thanks for your help

Ahmed

Answer (score 4):

There is no equivalent of javafx.io.Storage and javafx.io.Resource in JavaFX 2.x itself.  Because JavaFX 2.x is based on Java, you can use Java services.

The JNLP [FileSaveService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#FileSaveService) and [FileOpenService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/examples.html#FileOpenService) may be used.  These services should work across JNLP based deployments (browser embedded and webstart apps) - not sure if they work for standalone apps.

If you know that your application will be run as a standalone app or a signed browser embedded or webstart app with higher privileges, then you can get the user directory via the [user.home system property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) and write your app data to an an appropriate file location under that, probably using the [Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) api as in this [Files tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).  For example, use the Files api to create a `{$user.dir}/.myapp/appdata.dat` file to read and write.

JavaFX embeds an html5 web engine. The [WebEngine](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) in JavaFX 8 implements the offline storage portion of the html5 specification, the WebEngine in JavaFX 2.2 does not.

Comment: Can you please update your answer to address Desktop, Android, iOS, and web

Comment: @IlyaGazman  There is nothing to update.  There are no storage APIs in JavaFX.  If you want to store something locally on a given platform, you will need to research a Java compatible interface to the storage options on your platform of choice.  It doesn't mean that it is not possible, just that it is outside the scope of JavaFX and you need to use an additional API to support your storage needs.